# Request error mails using php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I am trying to send a mail with ajax and php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
      $(function() {
        $("#recibir").click(function() {
           var data = {
       
        email: $("#email").val(),
      
                };
                $.ajax({
                    
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://app.prabyc-proyectos.com/enviar-phpmailer.php",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(){
                        $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                });
    
            return false;
        });
    });
            </script>
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" id="myform" name="myform">
      
       <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="recibir" name="recibir" value="Recibir email"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    </form>
```

and I have these errors

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> http://app.prabyc-proyectos.com/enviar-phpmailer.php. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> POST http://www.app.prabyc-proyectos.com/enviar-phpmailer.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
> send
>
> m.extend.ajax
>
> (anonymous function) formulario-phpmailer.php
>
> m.event.dispatch
>
> r.handle

Comment: is that url on the same server as the script?

Comment: yeah is the same, when i send the mail directly from the action in the form works perfectly but not in the script!

Comment: What happens when you change the ajax call to: `url: "/enviar-phpmailer.php",`. If it's all on the same domain, that should get rid of the first error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the browser thinks that it's a cross origin request. I'm not sure what exactly is the problem, you have a url hardcoded in your ajax request statement. It probably is something very trivial, like a missing WWW, try adding that and see if it works ;)

Comment: Yeah if i add www solved the first problem. But no the second